# How do I convert arrayref to hashref in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have an array of hash like this:

```
[
    {
        'id'    => '6',
        'image' => '/x/eng/rlse/DOT/R9.0xN/final/bedrock/export/x86_64/tarball/image.tgz'
    },
    {
        'new_netboot_image' => '/x/eng/bbnbs/daemon/DOT/R9.2x/cit-ok/final/bedrock/export/x86_64/netboot/netboot/kernel',
        'version'           => '9.2',
        'ntest'             => '/x/eng/bbnbs/daemon/DOT/R9.2x/cit-ok/test/nate/bin/ntest',
        'nate_lib'          => '/x/eng/ctl/test-tools;/x/eng/ctl/test-tools/
    }
];
```

I want to pass this to a subroutine that accepts only hash reference. How do I do this? The above output is from the following dumper.

```
$Log->info("Dumping array after updating" . Dumper($orig_cleanup_version_settings));
        $Api->service_db->cleanup_version_mapping_update($orig_cleanup_version_settings);
```

Comment: You only showed a part of the structure. It's not an array ref.

Comment: You can't just crush an array into a hash somehow and hope your subroutine works. Everything depends on how the hash is being used.

Comment: Iterate over your array and call the function many times with each hash....or wrap the whole thing in an `{ }`...but that probably won't work unless the subroutine is very clever.

Comment: What I have is an array of hash. I need to pass as hash ref

Comment: [ {     
            'id' => '7',
            'image' => '/x/eng/bbnbs/daemon/DOT/R9.2x/cit-ok/final/bedrock/export/x86_64/tarball/image.tgz'
          }
        ];

Comment: Yes, you have said as much...what you have yet to clarify is what kind of structure the subroutine is expecting in that hash.

Comment: Okay, got you. This is the input validation of the subroutine:                           state $_param_spec = {
        'version'            => {'type' => SCALAR},
        'image'              => {'type' => SCALAR,          'optional' => 1},
        'nate_lib'           => {'type' => SCALAR|ARRAYREF, 'optional' => 1},
        'new_netboot_image'  => {'type' => SCALAR,          'optional' => 1},
        'ntest'              => {'type' => SCALAR,          'optional' => 1},
        'transaction'        => {'type' => SCALAR,          'default'  => 1},
    };

Comment: Which hashref do you need? Your arrayref, let it call `$ra`, has two items, both an hashref. So first one is `$ra->[0]` and second one is `$ra->[1]` . Noone can know for you which one do you need in your specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach that creates a hash reference based on your specs.  My `transaction` element baselessly speculates that it is the same as `id` in the input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dumper;

my $a = [
    {
        'id'    => '6',
        'image' => '/x/eng/rlse/DOT/R9.0xN/final/bedrock/export/x86_64/tarball/image.tgz'
    },
    {
        'new_netboot_image' => '/x/eng/bbnbs/daemon/DOT/R9.2x/cit-ok/final/bedrock/export/x86_64/netboot/netboot/kernel',
        'version'           => '9.2',
        'ntest'             => '/x/eng/bbnbs/daemon/DOT/R9.2x/cit-ok/test/nate/bin/ntest',
        'nate_lib'          => '/x/eng/ctl/test-tools;/x/eng/ctl/test-tools/'
    }
];

my $h = { map { %$_ } @$a };
$h->{ transaction } = delete $h->{ id };
print Dumper $h;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'image' => '/x/eng/rlse/DOT/R9.0xN/final/bedrock/export/x86_64/tarball/image.tgz',
          'new_netboot_image' => '/x/eng/bbnbs/daemon/DOT/R9.2x/cit-ok/final/bedrock/export/x86_64/netboot/netboot/kernel',
          'version' => '9.2',
          'ntest' => '/x/eng/bbnbs/daemon/DOT/R9.2x/cit-ok/test/nate/bin/ntest',
          'nate_lib' => '/x/eng/ctl/test-tools;/x/eng/ctl/test-tools/',
          'transaction' => '6'
        };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This saved me!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to aggregate the hashes in the array into a single hash

At a guess the data structure has been built incorrectly, resulting in two hashes instead of one. The best way would be to build the hash correctly in the first place, but this code will combine the data for you

```
my $data = [
    {
        'id'    => '6',
        'image' => '/x/eng/rlse/DOT/R9.0xN/final/bedrock/export/x86_64/tarball/image.tgz'
    },
    {
        'new_netboot_image' => '/x/eng/bbnbs/daemon/DOT/R9.2x/cit-ok/final/bedrock/export/x86_64/netboot/netboot/kernel',
        'version'           => '9.2',
        'ntest'             => '/x/eng/bbnbs/daemon/DOT/R9.2x/cit-ok/test/nate/bin/ntest',
        'nate_lib'          => '/x/eng/ctl/test-tools;/x/eng/ctl/test-tools/
    }
];

my %params;
{
    %params = ( %params, %$_ ) for values %$data;
}

my_sub(\%params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ref() to test the passed value. In the following example we pass a hash, and two hash refs, note that we only print values twice, even though three hashes were passed (two as refs). The strings: "HASH" "ARRAY" "SCALAR" can be used to test for references to structures, and the package string of a class such as "Foo::Bar" can be used to test for objects.

```
#! /bin/perl

use strict ; 

my %foo = ('foo' => 'bar') ; # hash
my $reffoo = \%foo ; # hashref
my $refbar = {'bar' => 'foo'} ; # hashref

sub only_hashref {
    return undef unless (ref($_[0]) eq 'HASH') ; 
    print ($_[0]->{'foo'}, "\n") if defined $_[0]->{'foo'} ; 
    print ($_[0]->{'bar'}, "\n") if defined $_[0]->{'bar'} ; 
}

only_hashref(%foo) ; 
only_hashref($reffoo) ; 
only_hashref($refbar) ;
```

Comment: The question is *"I want to pass this [data] to a subroutine that accepts only hash reference. How do I do this?"* You appear to have shown how to do something unrelated with an entirely different data structure.

Comment: Please don't set an example of working directly with the contents of `@_`. It's best to copy the values to named variables unless the subroutine is extremely brief, or it needs to modify any of the actual parameters.

Comment: Thanks for replying anyway.

Comment: Re: "It's best to copy the values to named variables",  When testing values, to remove them from the default array would corrupt the hash. To copy would use more memory, and to double reference would be even less readable. Testing @_ is done in dozens of main line packages on CPAN.